# C datatype 'long'- on Intel x86 64-bit machine

Tags: c

In the Intel document I have read that for Intel x86 64-bit machine, size of C datatype 'long' is 8 byte. 
But, when I run this simple code on my computer, which has intel(R) core(TM)i3 - 64-bit processor:

`printf("size of long, is %d", sizeof(long));`

Console output is 4 (instead of 8)! Can anybody explain this discrepancy or the reason for the same.
Thanks

Comment: Which os is installed , is it 32 bit or 64 bit OS.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: What compiler and which version? 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: Psychic debugging: You're on Windows. Microsoft's `long` is 32 bits, even on 64 bit builds, because of dumb attempts to maintain compatibility, so you have to use `long long`.

Comment: Do you have a link to this Intel document?

Comment: Wrong format specifier for `size_t`. The correct one is `%zu`. You are likely invoking undefined behaviour, unless you are on a 32 bit OS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All the C standard says is that `long` must be at least 32 bits, meaning that `sizeof(long) >= 4` (the unit of `sizeof`, which is called a byte, has 8 bits on virtually all platforms you're likely to encounter).

Each [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) defines things like the size of these types. You need to have compatible ABIs to link code compiled with different programs, so by and large there is one standard ABI for each type of processor *for each operating system*. This is only a trend: some operating systems have multiple ABIs, depending on what compiler and standard library are used.

Processor manufacturers often define an ABI, but then it's up to operating system and compiler vendors to decide whether to respect it.

On x86_64, Intel specifies a 64-bit `long`. This is what most OSes do, but there is one major exception: Windows. On Windows, the standard ABI (the one used by the system libraries and the vendor-provided development tools) has a 32-bit `long`. A 64-bit type is available as `int64_t` or `long long`.

Answer (score -1):

try `sizeof(unsigned long long)`, which should be 64bit.

long is probably 32-bit

Comment: `long` is not guaranteed to be 32-bit.

Comment: its guaranteed for windows. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx.

Comment: No, it is guaranteed for *certain* compilers *for* Windows.

Comment: Yes. OP seems to be using one of those (VS) on windows. If the OP had posted sizeof(long) returned 8, I'd not be arguing with you about this.  Are you looking for technically correct (considering all OS and compilers). I was providing an answer based on OP's observation. For a correct answer, why would you give a down vote?

Comment: just curious, which compiler on windows gives "8"?

Comment: OP does not mention Windows and your answer does not mention Windows - that is clarified later in the comments. Don't assume I am the one who downvoted. It's plausible that compilers designed on other platforms that have been ported to Windows may give different values, and if not, such a compiler could be created in the future.

Comment: I think gcc has an option to use whatever ABI you want, regardless of the host system.  Other than that, I'd bet that any compiler that can use the standard runtime libraries on Windows will have 32bit long.

Comment: @NeilKirk: Nandu is right. Microsoft specifically says that `LONG` is `long` is 32 bits. Since Microsoft defines what Microsoft Windows is and is not, this is their privilege. You obviously could create a compiler that had `sizeof(long)==8` but it would be misleading to call it a _Windows compiler_ since it explicitly violates the Windows API.